# read json value from another file and convert to array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here I am reading json value from different file and converting it to array:

```
include ('jsonp.php');
$json = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array('\r','\n'), $json);
$arr = json_decode($json, TRUE);
foreach ($arr as $r)
    {
        echo $r['post_content']."<br/>"
        echo $r['name']."<br/>";
        echo $r['taxonomy']."<br/><br/>";
    }
```

Above code gives all require converted values for this partial content:

`json.php` is :

https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/c1b87d3496780b80cd32

But same file with actual large content:

https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/3d17f57a342d5fe3fc1c

gives error in reading.

It gives :

```
arning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

in above code.

What can be issue?

Comment: we can't possibly answer your question without seeing the contents of `jsonp.php`. i also don't like your method of working with arrays.

Comment: @r3wt: sorry for it, but gist links are itself `json.php`

Comment: try json_last_error() to check for error.. also check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php example #1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's causing the issue is the newlines. You can check the validity thru [**`jsonlint.com`**](http://wwww.jsonlint.com). Handle them first before loading them to `json_decode()`.

Example:

```
$json = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $json); // group of new lines to just space
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($arr as $r) {
    echo $r['post_content'] . '<br/>';
    echo $r['name'] . '<br/>';
    echo $r['taxonomy'] . '<br/><hr/>';
}
```